# Timespan formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, timespan, cell-formatting

I'm currently using the custom format, **m:ss.00**, and it works perfectly for any times that exceed one minute, e.g. **1:02.47**. However, if I enter a time less than a minute, e.g. **57.66**, it gets transformed into **50:24.00**. I can get around this by entering **0:57.66**, but I'd rather not have to always type the leading **0:** and I don't want the leading **0:** displayed anyway. I'd like for it to understand that if I skip the number followed by a colon part, to interpret this as no minutes and simply display **57.66**.

Comment: Easy to do with VBA.  Is a macro approach acceptable to you??

Comment: Was hoping there was some simple format expression I could use rather than getting into VBA code. I suppose that may be my last resort option.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel datetimes:

```
1   =   1 day
```

*...therefore:*

```
1 / 24            =  1 hour    =  0.04166667  formatted as m:ss.00 is 0:00.00

1 / 24 / 60       =  1 minute  =  0.00069444  formatted as m:ss.00 is 1:00.00

1 / 24 / 60 / 60  =  1 second  =  0.00001157  formatted as m:ss.00 is 0:01.00
```

So if you have a number of seconds like `50.24`, you can convert it to Excel `DateTime` by dividing it by `x/24/60/60` which is the same as `x/86400`.

This will convert it to seconds.

The reason your method works if it's more than a minute is basically through the process of elimination.  A "real number" like `50.24` just looks like a number since it has no `:` colon or anything else to distinguish it as a datetime.  Entering intead `0:50.24` will force Excel to recognize it as a datetime.

Similarly, entering these dates:

```
12/01/1999
01/12/1999
```

...could have varying results (`January 12, 1999` or `December 1, 1999`) depending on your [regional settings](https://support.office.com/article/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989) (whether your country [uses `M/D/Y` or `D/M/Y`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)), however, entering either of these:

```
01/13/1999
13/01/1999
```

...will **both** be interpreted as "January 1, 1999" since Excel was able to eliminate other possibilities (since there's no 13th month).

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Working with Dates & Times in Excel**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel)
- Office.com : [**Change the Windows Regional Settings**](https://support.office.com/article/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989)
- Wikipedia : [**Date format by Country**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)
- Office.com : [**Add or Subtract Time**](https://support.office.com/article/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad)