# Excal VBA - Format("7A", "00") outputs "00" while Format("7B", "00") results to the desired output of "7A". Why are they different?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to list hexadecimal values from 7F down to 00 per Excel row. I achieved it by doing the following code:

```
Sub ListDownHex()
Dim StartValue, i As Integer
Dim nRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ActiveSheet
StartValue = 127 'memory location of 8051 RAM
nRow = 4

For i = StartValue To 0 Step -1
    sh.Range("A" & nRow) = Format(Right$("00" & Hex(i), 2), "00")
    nRow = nRow + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

except hex values that have "A" like "7A", "6A", "5A", etc. result to "00".
Further check on Intermediate Window confirms Format() function does it.

```
? Format("7B","00") 'desired output
7B
? Format("7A","00") 'not expected output
00
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Why are they acting differently?
(*Note: The focus of my question is on "strange" behavior of Format() not on my entire code.*)

Comment: `"7B"` is a string, so Format outputs it as is. `"7A"` is also a string, but Format converts it to `0.29166667` before formatting, I'm not immediately sure why. In any case, if you want a number formatted, then pass a number, not a string.

Comment: for some reason it is assuming that `7A` is `7 AM` which is `0.291667` and as such it is returning `00` with the format.

Comment: Ah, yes, "7A" is [understood as "7AM"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50317981/11683). Same for `"P"`/`"PM"`.

Comment: If one formats the cells as text THEN uses `Application.Text` instead of `Format` the error does not occur.

Comment: @ScottCraner Neither `Format` nor `Application.Text` is required in the first place. `Right$("00" & Hex(i), 2)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner for giving the logical answer for 7A.

Comment: And thank you too @GSerg for quick answers and shortening the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) is a complicated function that formats all sorts of things, dates and numbers included.

When you pass a string to it (which `"7A"` and `"7B"` are), it tries to see whether they can be converted to a number ([`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) returns True) or a date ([`IsDate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) returns True). If they can, it converts them, and only then applies formatting.

`IsDate()` returns True for `"7A"`, which is because "7A" is valid textual representation of time value "7 in the morning" (7am).
That, in turn, is because the short version of the [`AM/PM` formatting token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29993544/11683), `A/P`, returns the "am/pm" designator as "a/p":

```vb
? Format$(#07:00:00#, "hA/P")  ' => 7A
? Format$(#17:00:00#, "hA/P")  ' => 5P
```

So the string "7A" is first converted to a [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type) value `#12/30/1899 07:00:00#` (zero date, 7 in the morning). The numeric representation of that value is `0.29166667`, which, when formatted according to the "00" format, rounds to "00".

---

"7B", on the other hand, is not an `IsDate()`, so Format outputs it without changes like it does to strings that have no other meaning.

---

[In reality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) though, you do not need the `Format()` function at all, all you need is

```vb
= Right$("00" & Hex$(i), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow! so clear, and so complete. Thank you, @GSerg!

Allow me to refer to an error in exactly this regard made by Microsoft Support.
The following code was taken directly from Microsoft Support.

```
Function StrToHex (S As Variant) As Variant
'
' Converts a string to a series of hexadecimal digits.
' For example, StrToHex(Chr(9) & "A~") returns 09417E.
'
Dim Temp As String, I As Integer
If VarType(S) <> 8 Then
    StrToHex = S
Else
    Temp = ""
For I = 1 To Len(S)
    Temp = Temp & Format(Hex(Asc(Mid(S, I, 1))), "00")
Next I
StrToHex = Temp
End If
End Function
```

The URL is
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-records-in-case-sensitive-order-8fea1de4-6189-40e7-9359-00cd7d7845c0